# Cache json asynchronously

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, json, caching

I'm developing an iOS app which gets its data from a json feed of my server. Parsing the string is no problem... However, I am having trouble downloading the string asynchronously and then caching it. I found SDURLCache but do not know how to implement it. What is the best way to do this.

Comment: "having trouble downloading the string asynchronously and then caching it" -> Tell us how you download it and give us some code. It'll be easier to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could download the file to disk (synchronously):

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.yourprovider.com/your.json";
NSData *file = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[file writeToFile:<your file path> atomically:YES];
```

For asynchronous operations, instead, you should use NSURlConnection. After opening the connection,

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:<your NSURL>];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [conn start];
```

you receive data in this call back:

```
 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)_data {

 //here you could write to a NSFileHandle ivar:
 if (file)  { 

        [file seekToEndOfFile];

    } [file writeData:_data];
}
```